# How to show an open file native dialog with Electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, electron

I am trying to add functionality to my Electron app that will allow users to open a file in the app, specifically plain text files. After looking at the Electron documentation, I found [this](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/dialog/) page. I added this code to my `app.js` file, which I linked to in my `index.html`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dialog = require('electron');
$openFile = $('#openBtn');
$editor = $('#editor');

$openFile.click(function(){
  dialog.showOpenDialog(function(fileNames) {
    if (fileNames === undefined) return;
    var fileName = fileNames[0];

    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
      $editor.val(data);
    });
  });
});
```

However, when I run this, this error shows up in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: dialog.showOpenDialog is not a function` I have tried using remote, but to no avail.

Has anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;

document.querySelector('#selectBtn').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({
        properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']
    }, function (files) {
        if (files !== undefined) {
            // handle files
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The remote module is being deprecated (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408), consider using IPC instead.

Comment: @Benny Okay, I've read [the blog post linked from there](https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31#d978), but as an Electron newbie, what does that mean in the context of a file dialog? It seems like the suggestion at that post, "_Ideally, you should minimize the usage of IPC in your app—it’s better to keep as much work as you can in the renderer process,_" suggests they'd rather you write an in-app file selector, eg.

Comment: In my opinion, in general, it is a good practice to disable 'node integration', and enable 'context isolation' in the renderer process. Do as much work as you can in the renderer process, and delegate the remaining Node-specific work to the main process trough a [context bridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge). On this specific case, the native dialog have some additional features you can use, so it is up to the author to decide which route to take.

Comment: Not sure this code works anymore for electron 24.0.0

Answer (score 12):

On the main process you can use

```
const {dialog} = require('electron');

dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile'] }).then(function (response) {
    if (!response.canceled) {
        // handle fully qualified file name
      console.log(response.filePaths[0]);
    } else {
      console.log("no file selected");
    }
});
```

response looks like:

```
{
 canceled: false,
 filePaths: [
    '<fullpath>/<filename>'
 ]
}
```

Comment: This is the code that worked for me. The key was using the functional `then()` as a way of passing the continuation function we want to run after the showOpenDialog, which returns a promise.