# Electron select Directory with text input & onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, electron

```html
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Path to folder.">
<div class="box" id="choose-btn" onclick="chooseFolder()">...</div>
<div class="accept">Patch</div>
```

```js
let fdialog = require('nw-dialog');

function chooseFolder() {
    fdialog.folderBrowserDialog(".exe", function(result) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('input').innerHTML = result;
    })
}
```

I want to select a folder with `"#choose-btn"`,
the selected folder must be displayed in `".input"`,
if I click on Patch `".accept"` a file should be downloaded via link in the directory.

Comment: Why not use `Electron.remote` to get the Electron `dialog` and then use the awesome API that comes with it? (`dialog.showOpenDialog()`)? [Like This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849190/how-to-show-an-open-file-native-dialog-with-electron) or for your purpose `dialog.showSaveDialog()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Electron's native dialog box to choose the directory

```
      let { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

      function chooseFolder() {

        dir = dialog.showOpenDialog({
          properties: ['openDirectory']
        }, function(res){

          document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0].value = res[0];

        });

      }
```