# Electron - throws Not allowed to load local resource when using showOpenDialog

Tags: electron

I just wanted to use `showOpenDialog` and load an image. But when I select an image app will crash.

main.js:

```js
...
  ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {
    const window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

    dialog.showOpenDialog(window, {
      properties: ['openFile']
    }, p => {
      console.log(p)
    });
  })
```

renderer.js:

```js
document.querySelector('#select-image').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    ipcRenderer.send('open-file-dialog')
});
```

When I select anything this error shows in console : 
`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///start`
 and the Electron version is `8.2.5`

Edit 1:

This warning (or may be error) is shown in the terminal `objc[50899]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff951e61d0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x11298bdc8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

Edit 2:
I put together sample Gist using Electron Fiddle : [here](https://gist.github.com/547780a9f934fe8a75b78c09bb175690)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Electron doesn't allow windows with `webSecurity: true` to load local files.

### Bad solution

One way to get rid of the error is to simply set it to `false`. But this will make your app less safe to use:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    webSecurity: false
  }
})
```

### Good solution

Instead, what you have to do is to create a custom protocol and then use that for loading files.

### Step 1: Create a custom protocol

#### Main process:

```js
import { protocol } from 'electron'

...

app.on('ready', async () => {
  // Name the protocol whatever you want.
  const protocolName = 'your-app-name'

  protocol.registerFileProtocol(protocolName, (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.replace(`${protocolName}://`, '')
    try {
      return callback(decodeURIComponent(url))
    }
    catch (error) {
      // Handle the error as needed
      console.error(error)
    }
  })
  ...
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if the protocol name has to be unique, I never tested it. If you just name the protocol as `safe-protocol` and the user of your app has another app X with registered `safe-protocol`, your app will either throw an error when they open it or it will register both apps but when the user tries to open their app from a URL, using `app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient` function, both of those apps will open. Not sure what happens in this case.

### Step 2: use protocol to load files

#### Method 1: get path from the main process:

### Main process:

```js
ipcMain.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {
  const window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

  dialog.showOpenDialog(window, { properties: ['openFile'] })
    .then(result => {
      // Send the path back to the renderer
      event.sender.send('open-file-dialog-reply', { path: result.filePaths[0] })
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log('Could not get file path')
    })
})
```

#### Renderer process:

```html
<img id="image-1">
```

```js
ipcRenderer.on('open-file-dialog-reply', (event, data) => {
  const path = data.path
  loadImage(path)
}

function loadImage (path) {
  const image1 = document.getElementById('image-1')
  image1.src = `safe-file-protocol://${path}`
}
```

#### Method 2: load path directly in the renderer:

#### Renderer process:

```html
<img id="image-1" data-path="C:/test.jpg">
```

```js
function loadImage () {
  const image1 = document.getElementById('image-1')
  const path = image1.dataset.path
  image1.src = `safe-file-protocol://${path}`
}

loadImage()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error occur as soon as the dialog opens. It crashes even before trying to load the file. The `console.log(p)` doesn't run.

Comment: @Daniel I updated the answer and modified  `dialog.showOpenDialog`. Try it and see if it helps. That function is async, it returns a promise, why were you handling it like a callback?

Comment: My bad! I didn't notice that this was changed. Everywhere in the google it is handled by a function as third parameter like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849190/how-to-show-an-open-file-native-dialog-with-electron) or [here](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-showopendialog-tutorial/). I think they are out-dated. Thank you @Alex

Comment: @Daniel glad I could help :)

Comment: @Daniel I updated the answer again. Turns out, you have to decode the url with `decodeURIComponent(url)` to avoid errors when file names include non-English UTF-8 characters or characters like `#`. Just got these errors in my own app, so I thought, I should update the answer and let other people know about it.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me. For whatever reason, I was able to load files without `webSecurity: false` until I used `electron-forge`. After using it, I needed this custom-protocol fix.

Comment: I use it like that `<img src={'file-alternative://' + p.filename} alt={p.title}/>`, websecurity is still on. Your solution is a way better solution to make load an image/file in a dev server :) than most of what I found.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier I'm glad it was helpful to you