# Is there a way to load local files into HTML in Electron? Getting ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: electron, html5-audio

I have an Electron app that's trying to load a local audio file into an HTML5 `<audio>` element. The path itself is fine `file:///../song.mp3` and I've set `webSecurity` to `false`, but I'm still getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`. From that same error, if I copy the address and paste it into my browser, I get the correct file.

Are there any other settings I need to change to get this to work?

Appreciate your time

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible – Electron is made for making desktop apps, after all. Post the simplest example code showing what is triggering the error. And fwiw – I load HTML5 audio by setting the `audio` element`src` without any "file:///" prefix.

Comment: Do not set `webSecurity` to false. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623585/12125881) to learn how to load files safely.

Comment: @AlexHoffman Cheers, I just needed step 1 to get it to work with the safe protocol. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug. The URL scheme of the file is not enabling as a URL scheme.

You can use this code below inside of `app.on('ready'....`:

```js
protocol.registerFileProtocol('file', (request, cb) => {
    const url = request.url.replace('file:///', '')
    const decodedUrl = decodeURI(url)
    try {
      return cb(decodedUrl)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('ERROR: registerLocalResourceProtocol: Could not get file path:', error)
    }
  })
```

it will be fixed