# HTML5 Audio long buffering before playing

Tags: audio, electron, buffer, html5-audio, data-uri

I'm currently making an electron app that needs to play some 40Mbyte audio file from the file system, maybe it's wrong to do this but I found that the only way to play from anywhere in the file system is to convert the file to a dataurl in the background script and then transfer it using icp, after that I simply do

```js
this.sound = new Audio(dataurl);
this.sound.preload = "metadata"
this.sound.play()
```

(part of a VueJS component hence the this)

I did a profling inside electron and this is what came out:
[image: Profiler]

Note that actually transferring the 40Mbytes audio file doesn't take that long (around 80ms) what is extremely annoying is the "Second Task" which is probably buffering (I have no idea) which last around 950ms, this is way too long and ideally would need it under <220ms

I've already tried changing the preload option to all available options and while I'm using the native html5 audio right now I've also tried howlerjs with similar results (seemed a bit faster tho).

I would guess that loading the file directly might be faster but even after disabling security measures put by electron to block the file:/// it isn't recognized as a valid URI by XHR

Is there a faster way to load the dataurl since all the data is there it just needs to be converted to a buffer or something like that ?

Note: I can not "pre-buffer" every file in advance since there is about 200 of them it just wouldn't make sense in my opinion.

**Update:**
I found this post [Electron - throws Not allowed to load local resource when using showOpenDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623156/electron-throws-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-when-using-showopendialog/61623585#61623585)
don't know how I missed it, so I followed step 1 and I now can load files inside electron with the custom protocol, however, nor Audio nor howlerjs is faster, it's actually slower at around 6secs from click to first sound, is it that it needs to buffer the whole file before playing ?

**Update 2:**
It appears that the 6sec loading time is only effective on the first instance of audio that is created. I do not know why tho. After that the use of two instances (one playing and one pre-buffering) work just fine, however even loading a file that isn't loaded is instantaneous. Seems weird that it only is the firs one.

Comment: I don't use Electron, but yes, converting it to a data URI is definitely the wrong way to go about it.  That would involve base64 encoding the entire file, shoving it into a script to then turn around and decode again.  Why are you using XHR?  XHR isn't going to work on a local file.  Why can't you simply use `new Audio(... path to actual file here ...)`?  Does Electron disable that sort of access?  (And if so, how do you load any other resources, like images?)  Even if you needed to use Fetch/XHR, you could get the resource as a blob and create an object URL for it.

Comment: I agree about b64 not being the way to go, however I can't ask the user to put the audio files in a specific place (they are stored in a db, etc ...). XHR was only because of howlerjs which use it but event with the `new Audio(...)` the file:/// isn't recognized as a valid uri. I'll look into the blob thing tho

Comment: Where does the audio file come from?  The audio data itself is stored in a database?  How do you fetch it?

Comment: I'm making an audiobook player so right now the user select a path from his file system it scans all files (to get the chapters), get the datauri of the first one send it to the frontend and play it

Comment: Is this done with a normal file picker?  If so, you can use `URL.createObjectURL(file)` on the file object directly.

Comment: Yes and no, it is a normal file pick but it save all files into a database after scan (to display all books in a library) and I can select a book and it will find the path of the first chapter and play that

Comment: Can you show what you're currently doing for XHR?

Comment: As I said I'm not using it right now, I said that XHR was used by howlerjs and I used howlerjs but it did not change a thing.

Comment: Alright, well, I could probably help you figure this out if you could show how it is you plan to load these files, but I can't do that with the vague notion that the files are coming from somewhere, possibly database, possibly folder.  :-)  Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry you didn't understand, think of it like you only have the absolute file path in the frontend, also see my update :)