# How to access system filepicker from Electron appmenu?

Tags: electron

I been trying to get the basics of Electron figured out, and I don't really know what documentation would cover how to access native stuff from the app menu.  How would you launch a typical "File open..." dialog, like VSCode?  I pulled [that open source repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode), but they have some sort of attribute (decorator) system that I'm not following.  This feels so basic... but I expect it will be different depending on the platform.  I"m only concerned with desktop, for this question.
*Thanks!*

Comment: Note that there have been changes to how you're supposed to call these dialogs (using IPC instead of the remote module). As for documentation, have you looked at the [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options)?

Comment: The accepted and most upvoted answer in the question [How to show an open file native dialog with Electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849190/how-to-show-an-open-file-native-dialog-with-electron) uses `(electron).remote`. This was removed from Electron some time ago and is no longer recommended. You need to be familar with Electrons [Menu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu) , [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog) modules. Add the code you currently have to your question for more help.